# Entering distrobox changes the display resolution

Tags: fedora, container, resolution

In a Fedora 39 kinoite VM, I have a Distrobox container with Ubuntu22.04.
 When I first created the container the display had a resolution of 1280x800.

I changed the display resolution to 1280x1024 and, if I restart the VM, its resolution is the new one.
However, doing Distrobox enter to the container Ubuntu22.04 the display resolution rolls-back to 1280x800.

The resolution changes when starting the distrobox at `firing init` step.